# Website disk space and loading speed

Tags: web-server, performance, web-hosting, website, page-speed

I was wondering if the loading speed of my website is affected by my disk space.

For example, my current used disk space is 5GB and most of my files are videos which users can only download. If my home page consists of simply text and few images less than 500kb in total, will its loading speed be affected by my disk space in any way? Or is the speed only affected on pages where I have large amount of content?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Typical* requests are **entirely unaffected** by type/usage/status/load of hard disks. This is because typical requests are served from various caches - most obviously: RAM.

While typical hard disks do have performance difference in their sequential read speed depending on where on the disk the content is stored - sequential read speed is generally less important than seek time (the time required to get to your file, as opposed to the time required to read your file), as typical website requests require loading of relatively small files.

Your disk space will only affect your website loading speed, and even then **to a usually insiginificant degree** if all of the following is the case:

1. no caches used (e.g. server just restarted)
2. the server is actually using a HDD (and not, e.g. an SSD)
3. the requested file is huge (think of something in the order of tens of megabytes) or a large number of files is requested (who are stored in different positions on the disk)

If you wish to explore the factors that *do* impact your website loading speed, you will need to clarify further which components of "speed" are important to you, the terms you want to research will be "TTFB" and "time to first render", "full load".